# How can I map objects to reach output with the same index?

Tags: reactjs

So I've got something like this:

```
    const data = {
        first: ["a", "b", "c"],
        second: ["a", "b", "c"],
        third: ["a", "b", "c"]
    };

    return (
         <div>
             {
               Object.keys(data).map( keys => data[keys])
               // output: abcabcabc
               // expected: aaabbbccc
             }
         </div>
    );
```

and have no idea how to map object to reach data of the same index.

Any solution?

Comment: Can't you just sort it before you return?

Comment: Don't think so, cause I'd like to add random data to return all data of specific index in 1 html element, so it could generate them and more index data I will add then more elements will be dynamically generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const data = {
  first: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  second: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  third: ['g', 'h', 'i']
};

const values = Object.values(data);
const res = values[0].reduce(
  (a, _, i) => (values.forEach(v => (a += v[i])), a),
  ''
);

console.log(res);
```